# Is there a fast and free alternative to MATLAB regarding matrix calculations?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, octave

I am looking for a fast and free alternative to MATLAB regarding matrix calculations (inversions, etc).
MATLAB is fast but also expensive.
Besides, as it is an interpreted language, I think there must be libraries for compiled languages which can achieve the same matrix operations faster.
I know Octave but I have heard it is slower than MATLAB...
Does anyone know of something?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for a recommended tool. Do your own research. Google is your friend.

Comment: "`I know Octave but I have heard it is slower than MATLAB`" -- Did you actually try it out or are you just going by whatever people say.

Comment: I dare claim that currently Matlab beats all its clones when it comes to performance (not all similar products are clones of course). However, if you are looking for something free just pick what you like, most performance differences are not that extreme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `C++`, I suggest [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

I think that python with some library like [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) and [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) can be a good solution. (Python is not a strictly compiled language, but most of the libraries are written in C/C++ and are pretty fast).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the unofficial OpenGL Math Library GLM. It should have everything you should need.

http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html